# How to generate an alphanumeric tree changes with criteria?

Tags: excel, vba, tree, alphanumeric, generate

I'm working on excel sheet template used for SAP System and I have 2 columns looks like below:

```
Column C               Column E
Level                  Element Code
3                      ABCD.01.01.01               
4                      ABCD.01.01.01.01
4                      ABCD.01.01.01.02
4                      ABCD.01.01.01.03
3                      ABCD.01.01.02
4                      ABCD.01.01.02.01 'I Want to Restart Numbering Here
4                      ABCD.01.01.02.02
4                      ABCD.01.01.02.03
```

I succeeded in level 3 to be automated in the whole sheet by Macro as below

```
Sub AutoNumber3()

Dim Rng, C As Range
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng = Worksheets("Union").Range("C2:C" & Lrow)
i = 1
For Each C In Rng.Cells
If C.Value = 3 Then
For i = 1 To i Step 1
C.Offset(0, 2).Value = "ABCD.01.01." & i
Next i
End If
Next C
End Sub
```

and I used the same for level 4 as below

```
Sub AutoNumber4()
Dim Rng, C As Range
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng = Worksheets("Union").Range("C2:C" & Lrow)
i = 1
For Each C In Rng.Cells
If C.Value = 4 Then
For i = 1 To i Step 1
C.Offset(0, 2).Value = "ABCD.01.01.01" & i
Next i
End If
Next C
End sub
```

I want to Restart the numbering of level 4 from 1 each time the cells values in the level column = 3 by using Do Until the next C.Value = 3, I = 1 But I can not put it correctly in the Autonumber4 procedure

Your help is highly appreciated since this sheet may reach to 50000 or 100000 rows which is impossible to fill them manually

Thanks, Regards

Moheb Labib

Comment: Declare always variables, right now `rng` is Variant. Also, you declare `i=1` and then you do `For i=1 to i step 1`. It make no sense, if you are going to do it just once, you don't need a For...Next. Also, have you tried doind this with normal Excel formulas? Also, would all of the counts have 2 digits? You say there are more than 100.000 rows. How would be represented row 95.000?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Sub AutoNumber()
    Dim rngLevels As Range, cl As Range
    Dim lLastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim sElemCode As String
    Dim vLevelsCounter() As Long
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Union")
        lLastRow = Evaluate("=COUNTA(" & .Name & "!C:C)")
        lLastRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(lLastRow, .Cells(Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
        Set rngLevels = .Range("C2:C" & lLastRow)
    End With
    
    For Each cl In rngLevels.Cells
        ' Uncomment "If" to use it on filtered data only
        'If Not cl.EntireRow.Hidden Then
            UpdateLevelsCounters vLevelsCounter, cl.Value
            
            sElemCode = "ABCD"
            For i = 1 To cl.Value
                sElemCode = sElemCode & "." & Format(vLevelsCounter(i), "00")
            Next i
            cl.Offset(0, 2).Value = sElemCode
        'End If
    Next cl
End Sub

Function UpdateLevelsCounters(ByRef arr() As Long, lLevel As Long)
    If lLevel < 1 Then Exit Function
    
    Dim i As Long
    ReDim Preserve arr(1 To lLevel)
    
    For i = LBound(arr) To lLevel - 1
        If arr(i) = 0 Then arr(i) = 1
    Next i
    arr(lLevel) = arr(lLevel) + 1
End Function
```

This should work for levels other than 3 and 4 as well (I hope)

[image]

Comment: WOW, you are the man, Thanks a lot, it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You've not specified if your count will be always of two digits or not, and if it can be something like `01.20.99.99`, but This formula can lead you in the good way (not tested with 100000 records)

[image]

```
=IF(C2=3;"ABCD.01.01."&TEXT(COUNTIF($C$2:C2;C2);"00");INDIRECT("E"&SUMPRODUCT(MAX(--($C$2:C2=3)*ROW($C$2:C2))))&"."&TEXT(SUMPRODUCT(--($C$2:C2=4)*--(ROW($C$2:C2)>SUMPRODUCT(MAX(--($C$2:C2=3)*ROW($C$2:C2)))));"00"))
```

This is how it works:

A) First, we check if cell in colum C is a 3 or 4. In case is 3, we do `;"ABCD.01.01."&TEXT(COUNTIF($C$2:C2;C2);"00");` This will count how many times does the number 3 appear in range `$C$2:C2` and will concatenate to string `ABCD.01.01.` The trick here is using `$C$2:C2`, because it makes a range dynamic (**but it can overload calculus times**)

B) If not 3, then we do a really complext part I'm going to try to explain. Also, we use the trick of dynamic range

1. `SUMPRODUCT(MAX(--($C$2:C2=3)*ROW($C$2:C2))))` this part is used twice. It will get the last row number of the last 3 value in column C.
   *Example*:`ROW($C$2:C6)` will get an array of just row numbers, like `{2;3;4;5;6}`. `--($C$2:C6=3)` will return an array of zero/one depending if cell equals/not equals to 3, something like `{1;0;0;0;1}`. `($C$2:C6=3)*ROW($C$2:C6))` will multiply both arrays, so we get `{1;0;0;0;1}*{2;3;4;5;6}={2;0;0;0;6}`. And with MAX we get max value from that array, That 6 means the last position of a 3 value.
2. We use INDIRECT combined with the number of step 1 to get the text inside the cell
3. `SUMPRODUCT(--($C$2:C2=4)*--(ROW($C$2:C2)>SUMPRODUCT(MAX(--($C$2:C2=3)*ROW($C$2:C2)))));"` Everything after the `>` is the same logic than step 1. It will return the row number of last cell containing a 3. Part `SUMPRODUCT(--($C$2:C2=4)*--(ROW($C$2:C2)` will just get row numbers of those cells containing a 4 value, and which row numbers **are higher** than value obtained in step 1. That way you make sure how to count the cells containing 4 values, between two cells containing 3 values.
4. We concatenate everything to form the final string.
5. TEXT functions are just used to force the calculation to be 2 digits.

You can use this manually, or you can insert the formula using VBA, drag down, and then converting everything into values (I would probably would do that). Something like this could work.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim LR As Long

LR = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'last non blank row in column c

Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-2]=3,""ABCD.01.01.""&TEXT(COUNTIF(R2C3:RC[-2],RC[-2]),""00""),INDIRECT(""E""&SUMPRODUCT(MAX(--(R2C3:RC[-2]=3)*ROW(R2C3:RC[-2]))))&"".""&TEXT(SUMPRODUCT(--(R2C3:RC[-2]=4)*--(ROW(R2C3:RC[-2])>SUMPRODUCT(MAX(--(R2C3:RC[-2]=3)*ROW(R2C3:RC[-2]))))),""00""))"
Range("E2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("E2:E" & LR) = Range("E2:E" & LR).Value 'paste into values
End Sub
```

**NOTE:** Probably you will need to adapt this depending on the results (we do not know if the count of 3 or 4 values can have 3 or 4 digits, and so on).